# git bash fail to push branch with error message: "object directory does not exist"

Tags: git, bash

recently I've updated my Git Bash to the latest version and now when I'm trying to push a branch to the remote server I get an error message:

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin bugs/purlin_support_reactions
Counting objects: 41, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (41/41), done.
Writing objects: 100% (41/41), 4.91 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 41 (delta 33), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: object directory /192.168.10.1/strengs/strengs_master.git/objects does not exist; check .git/objects/info/alternates.
remote: fatal: unresolved deltas left after unpacking
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To //192.168.10.1/strengs/strengs_master.git
 ! [remote rejected] bugs/purlin_support_reactions -> bugs/purlin_support_reactions (unpacker error)
```

> error: failed to push some refs to '//192.168.10.1/strengs/strengs_master.git'

The object directory does exist (checked), `check .git/objects/info/alternates` does not exist. In info there is only `packs` file. 
 
What could go wrong?

Comment: add `refs/` in front of `bugs/purlin_support_reactions`?
Your "destination" refspec is weird. It should be similar to what you list with `git branch -a`.

Comment: Well hitting git remote -v gives, so this gives me my remote location which is correct:         $ git remote -v
origin  //192.168.10.1/strengs/strengs_master.git (fetch)
origin  //192.168.10.1/strengs/strengs_master.git (push)

Comment: This is a bug in git. I can reproduce it. I'll look into it. As a work-around, you can mount `\\192.168.10.1\strengs` under a drive letter, say `Z:` and push to `Z:/strengs_master.git`.

Comment: @j6t Work-around was successful. Thanks! Anyway git should be able to handle such origin destinations. May be we can escape it with \\\192.168.10.1\...?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So in general. In *git version 2.11.0.windows.1* if your origin destination begins with \\192.168....or similar the first backslash for some reason is ignored (kind of bug). Workaround - mount network drive i.o. \\192.168....

**EDIT:** This issue must be solved with upgrade to git v2.12.0

Answer (score 6):

This is a known issue which is outlined on the git-for-windows github issue tracker page https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/979

Comment: Note: This was added to the v2.11.1 milestone on Dec 23, 2016 - https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/milestone/6?closed=1